# IBM xSeries 306 CPU Speed

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit, ibm, ibm-xseries

I have an IBM xSeries 306.  The system has been flawless until a week ago.  It's a Pentium 4 Dual Core CPU.  The CPU speed is 3.20 gHz.  Now, it shows 4.26 gHz or 2.16 gHz when the POST screen comes up.  Nothing in the BIOS is user configurable for this.

Anyone have an idea what's going on here?  If it's not at 3.20 gHz, it runs slower.

Thanks!

Comment: The Mobo had some leaky caps around the CPU.  I changed the caps out and the problem still exists, so I just replaced the Mobo with a unit off of eBay.  $40 and I'm back up and running.

Comment: Bob, you should post that as an answer to your own question and accept it.  That's perfectly fine here on SF.  That way the question doesn't show in the Unanswered Questions section.